# Does it matter setting parquet.block.size, when writing to s3 or gs?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

We know setting `parquet.block.size` to HDFS block size is recommended, but **this matters for HDFS**.

1. When writing to **cloud storages** like **s3** or **gs**, Does it
   matter setting `parquet.block.size`
2. What happens to parallelism, for downstream jobs using this data in
   cases like below?

For ex:

If i write spark dataframe, of ~ 20 GB to s3 or gs

- each .parquet file size of 2 GB, with setting parquet.block.size =
  512 MB
- each .parquet file size of 2 GB, with setting parquet.block.size = 64
  MB

Answer (score 1):

Yes, block size can still matter for S3.  If you want to use [S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectSELECTContent.html) to query rows out of the parquet files, there are upper limits on block size you can use.  From "[Selecting Content from Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/selecting-content-from-objects.html#selecting-content-from-objects-requirements-and-limits)" for S3 Select:

> Additional limitations apply when using Amazon S3 Select with Parquet
>   objects:
>
> - ...
> - The maximum uncompressed block size is 256 MB.